# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libNBioBSP.so"

Tags: java, android, android-fingerprint-api

I'm encountering a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError related to the library "`libNBioBSP.so`" after updating your API version to 34 and configuring the NDK with specific ABI filters.

"After updating my API version from 31 to 34, I added the following NDK configuration to address compatibility issues:

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a" 
}
```

This resolved the initial '`This app isn't compatible with the latest version of Android`' warning. However, when attempting to use the fingerprint device, I encountered a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` with the message '`dlopen failed: library "libNBioBSP.so`".' Despite several attempts, I have been unable to resolve this issue."

When I click on my fingerprint access layout I get this error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libNBioBSP.so"`

Comment: I got the issue after adding arm64-v8a is in NDK